# Intel S5520UR SSD compatibility

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I trying to chose SSD for Intel S5520UR serverboard.

I know that this serverboard does not support SATA III interface and I'am finding something with higher performance than supported SATA II.

I'am looking to the PCI-E SSD and really can not chose on which to stop my choice.

There are PCI-E SSD devices and PCI-E M.2. What type support my Intel S5520UR board? Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [manual for the motherboard](https://ark.intel.com/products/36456/Intel-Server-Board-S5520UR%20the%20manual) your board has PCI-e x16 and PCI-e x8 slots. It does not have any M2 slots.

Thus you would need either:

1. A Native PCI-e SSD
2. Or a PCI-e to M.2 convertor (and if you want to boot off that support in your motherboards firmware).
3. Or a SAS (HBA or RAID) card and a SAS or SATA SSD.
4. Or a SATA card (plain SATA or RAID) and a SATA SSD.

I suggest looking at which slots are already in use. And then deciding on reliability. SATA is not recommended in servers since failing SATA drives can bring a whole system down, whereas SAS has proper error recovery.

But a SAS SSD or a fusion PCI-e card (or similar) might be over your budget. Or at least might not make economical sense given that you use such an old motherboard.